# Standardize or not standardize before clustering

Tags: clustering, standardization, euclidean, weighted-data

Objects in my sample have multiple dimensions. Some dimensions are measured in kilometers and some in kilograms, there are also categorical variables that I need to quantify. I am planning to use weighted Euclidean distance in cluster analysis. My question is: Should I standardized (subtract mean and divide by standard deviation) each dimension before studying clustering?

Comment: check the first comment here, it applies (it is not a clustering question) http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65762/how-to-standardize-data-for-hierarchical-clustering Also, it depends eg http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01897163

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noticed, your columns have different scales, so you will need to do something about that. Standardization is a good first attempt, but:

- manual or learned weights will likely be better.
- weighting is redundant to normalization (both are a linear trasformation).
- neither will "just work". Plan how to evaluate the quality of your distance function.

Comment: Do you have any readings or suggestions on how to 'evaluate the quality of your distance function'?